# Fill polygon with pattern doesn't work with leaflet

Tags: svg, polygon, leaflet, fill

I try to render a SVG polygon filled with pattern. SVG.path filled with pattern doesn't work. As you can see in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QqLLF/1/), filled background shows up transparent in Firefox and black in Chrome.

The example is based on [leaflet GeoJSON Example](http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson.html) and uses the diagonalHatch pattern described by [carto.net](http://www.carto.net/svg/samples/patterns.shtml).

```
<defs>
    <pattern id="diagonalHatch" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="105" height="105">
        <g style="fill:none; stroke:black; stroke-width:1">
            <path d="M0 90 l15,15"/><path d="M0 75 l30,30"/>
            <path d="M0 60 l45,45"/><path d="M0 45 l60,60"/>
            <path d="M0 30 l75,75"/><path d="M0 15 l90,90"/>
            <path d="M0 0 l105,105"/><path d="M15 0 l90,90"/>
            <path d="M30 0 l75,75"/><path d="M45 0 l60,60"/>
            <path d="M60 0 l45,45"/><path d="M75 0 l30,30"/>
            <path d="M90 0 l15,15"/>
        </g>
    </pattern>
</defs>
```

As this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vkrw2/1/) shows, copying the SVG polygons below the map, makes it work on Chrome but not on Firefox. Apply a fill pattern adding this style to SVG.path:

```
style="fill: url(#diagonalHatch)"
```

I'm really not sure if this is a bug in leaflet or some conflict with SVG implementation on Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: The prepend adds the pattern to the html namespace rather than the svg namespace. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642035/jquerys-append-not-working-with-svg-element for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've wrote a leaflet plugin for this, you may try it,
https://github.com/lnaweisu/leaflet-polygon-fillPattern

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try setting the path via the shape's attribute as mentioned in this thread: [Leaflet polygon with fuzzy outline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28237435/891965)

```
// Set filter attribute on the polygon
polygon._path.setAttribute('filter', 'url(#blur)');
```