# Leaflet polygon with fuzzy outline

Tags: javascript, css, svg, maps, leaflet

I am looking for a way to have a fuzzy/blur/gradient outline of a leaflet polygon.

This should help make country outlines more simple (currently, when you zoom in to a svg representing a country, it gets ugly/inaccurate).

I was thinking about attaching CSS attributes to the svg similiar to this: http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_fegaussianblur.asp
But apparently the svg subelement `<g>` (used for the leaflet polygon) does not accept this.

I also had a look at `<defs>` of svg (see here: http://geoexamples.blogspot.be/2014/01/d3-map-styling-tutorial-ii-giving-style.html) but have no clue in applying this to leaflet.

http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start-example.html

[image: example illustration]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would first need to put the actual `filter` element into the `svg` element of the map, otherwise assigning a filter to a `path` or `g` won't work because the filter will be undefined. So you're going to need to do this in Javascript. But assigning a filter by classname in CSS is as far as i can see impossible because it will only work with the `url()` function of CSS. That won't fly with the dynamic SVG embedded in Leaflet's overlaypane. You can however assign it with Javascript:

```
// Get the SVG element from the overlayPane
var svg = map.getPanes().overlayPane.firstChild,
    // Create filter element
    svgFilter = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'filter'),
    // Create blur element
    svgBlur = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'feGaussianBlur');

// Set ID attribute of filter
svgFilter.setAttribute('id', 'blur');

// Give room to blur to prevent clipping
svgFilter.setAttribute('x', '-100%');
svgFilter.setAttribute('y', '-100%');
svgFilter.setAttribute('width', '500%');
svgFilter.setAttribute('height', '500%');

// Set deviation attribute of blur
svgBlur.setAttribute('stdDeviation', 3);

// Append blur element to filter element 
svgFilter.appendChild(svgBlur);
// Append filter element to SVG element
svg.appendChild(svgFilter);
```

After that you can use the filter on polygons, linestrings, etc:

```
// Creating a polygon and adding to the map
var polygon = L.polygon([[10, 10],[-10,10], [-10,-10],[10,-10]]).addTo(map);

// Set filter attribute on the polygon
polygon._path.setAttribute('filter', 'url(#blur)');
```

That's it, here's a working example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/JTNgeXuiBaL8LIbmkVjz?p=preview

Comment: Thanks! That's very close to what I want to achieve. I modified your plunker a bit:
http://plnkr.co/edit/xmjgwxSAo4TJx7ZfgAhr?p=preview

Only one problem: when you scroll out, the edges of the `<g> become very sharp. Any idea to make it "overflow" the edges of the `<g>?

Comment: No thanks, you're welcome, just accept the answer if it's the solution to your problem. I see what you mean. I've set the blur on the actual `path` element not on the `g` element, but i've tried setting it on the `g` element: `polygon._container.setAttribute('filter', 'url(#blur)');` (container is the actual `g` element) and that renders exacty the same when zooming. When i have some time i'll do some more experimenting but i'm guessing that's just the way it is or would need to do something expensive like removing and add the polygons on zoom if that will work and is an option performancewise

Comment: Yes I guess `<g> have no actual width or style, but is only the container for the svg children, here a path. So the overflow (if possible) would have to be applied on the path element. But adding overflow="visible" does not seem to do anything.

Comment: After some research, i know now that overflow won't work: "The overflow attribute applies to elements that establish new viewports (see below), <pattern> elements and <marker> elements. For all other elements, the property has no effect." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/overflow I think the solution lies in `filterUnits`, see http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html#FilterEffectsRegion I've had some luck with setting `width` and `height` of the filter but i think the key is the `x` an `y` coordinates. See update plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/JTNgeXuiBaL8LIbmkVjz?p=preview

Comment: Sorry forgot to freeze :) As you can see, it works correctly on the right and bottom now which leads me to think that moving the actual filter effect region by using the `x` and `y` coordinates will do it. Haven't had any luck with that so far, because i guess i need the correct coordinates for the path and i haven't got much time at the moment to test/play around now.

Comment: That's it! http://plnkr.co/edit/tis1feSfRnt3VZ8g9qOf?p=preview
Adding the two lines svgFilter.setAttribute('x', '-100%');
svgFilter.setAttribute('y', '-100%'); did the trick

Comment: Way to go :) I'll edit that into the answer, for when other users with the same question find it. Glad it's working now, gave an upvote, nice question!